# What's the best way to go about getting the next set of results from the api and then append to a CollectionView?

Tags: json.net, maui

At the very end of the json returned from the API I'm using, there is a "next" element.  I've worked out that I need to append this to the api url to get the next set of 10 results, and so on.  What I haven't worked out is how to do this.  Do I make a new RestClient/httpclient to get the next set of results? If so, how do I go about appending the results I get back to the CollectionView with the first 10 results in it?  Is there any documentation that shows how this is supposed to be done? (not seeing it in the Maui docs, but I could be overlooking it). Thanks!

**EDIT FROM ERROR MENTIONED IN COMMENTS**
I've added some things from the documentation into the View:

```
<CollectionView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Posts}"
    BackgroundColor="#1C1D20"
    RemainingItemsThreshold="5"
    RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached">
```

and to the ViewModel:

```
async void OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object nextPage = Data.Next;
    Console.WriteLine("Next Page: " + nextPage);
    var request = new RestRequest(endPoint);
    var content = await client.GetAsync(request);

    //set json options
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    };

    if (content.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
    {
        Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content.Content, options);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
    }
}
```

but now I'm getting a warning and an error (that I believe may be related):

> The local function 'OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached' is declared but never used

> EventHandler "OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached" with correct signature not found in type "App.Views.HomePage".

I'm not sure what to make of these, since the warning I would expect due to the threshold being reached being what fires off the event - and I have no idea what the second one means.

**EDIT 2: Problems moving the event handler to the code behind**
I've moved the event handler to the code behind instead of the ViewModel, and the funtion that does the work into the ViewModel.

**ViewModel**

```
using App.Models;
using RestSharp;
using System.Text.Json;
using RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson;

namespace App.ViewModels;

public partial class PostsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //Get Root Data
    private Root _Data;
    public Root Data { get => _Data; set { _Data = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data)); } }
    
    //Get Pagination Data
    private Root _next;
    public Root Next { get => _next; set { _next = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Next)); } }

    //Get Posts Data
    private string _body;
    public string Body { get => _body; set { _body = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Body)); } }
    private string _communityName;
    public string CommunityName { get => _communityName; set { _communityName = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CommunityName)); } }
    private string _createdAt;
    public string CreatedAt { get => _createdAt; set { _createdAt = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CreatedAt)); } }
    private string _downvotes;
    public string Downvotes { get => _downvotes; set { _downvotes = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Downvotes)); } }
    private string _isPinned;
    public string IsPinned { get => _isPinned; set { _isPinned = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPinned)); } }
    private string _noComments;
    public string NoComments { get => _noComments; set { _noComments = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NoComments)); } }
    private string _title;
    public string Title { get => _title; set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title)); } }
    private string _type;
    public string Type { get =>  _type; set { _type = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Type)); } }
    private string _upvotes;
    public string Upvotes { get => _upvotes; set { _upvotes = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Upvotes)); } }
    private string _username;
    public string Username { get => _username; set { _username = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username)); } }
    
    //Get Post Image Data
    private Models.Image _Image;
    public Models.Image Image { get => _Image; set { _Image = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Image)); } }
    private string _imageurl;
    public string ImageUrl { get => _imageurl; set { _imageurl = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageUrl)); } }

    //Get Post Link Data
    private Link _Link;
    public Link Link { get => _Link; set { _Link = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Link)); } }
    private string _linkurl;
    public string LinkUrl { get => _linkurl; set { _linkurl = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LinkUrl)); } }
    private string _hostname;
    public string Hostname { get => _hostname; set { _hostname = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Hostname)); } }

    //Method Variables to be accessed in the code behind
    public string baseUrl { get; set; }
    public string endPoint { get; set; }
    public RestClient Client { get; set; }

    public async Task LoadPosts()
    {
        //create a request to the api
        string baseUrl = "https://discuit.net/api";
        var clientoptions = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl)
        {
            //Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("discapp", "testing123")
        };
        var Client = new RestClient(
                            clientoptions,
                            configureSerialization: s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson()
        );
        //client.AddDefaultParameter("feed", "all");      //One of: home, all, community.
        //client.AddDefaultParameter("filter", "all");    //One of: all, deleted, locked. If not set, all is the default.*
        //client.AddDefaultParameter("sort", "hot");      //One of: latest, hot, activity, day, week, month, year, all.
        string endPoint = "/posts";
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint);
        var content = await Client.GetAsync(request);

        //set json options
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        };

        if (content.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content.Content, options);
            Console.WriteLine("Status OK");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
        }
    }

    //get next data function to be called from the code behind
    public async void FetchNextData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Threshold Reached");

        //create a request to the api with the next page string
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint + "?" + Data.Next);

        //get next results
        var content = await Client.GetAsync(request);

        //set json options
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        };

        if (content.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status OK");
            Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content.Content, options);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
        }
    }

}
```

**Code Behind**

```
using App.ViewModels;

namespace App.Views;

public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    PostsViewModel vm;

    public HomePage()
    {
        BindingContext = vm = new PostsViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        //string next = vm.Data.Next;
        await vm.LoadPosts();
    }

    async void OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Threshold Reached");
        await Task.Run(() => vm.FetchNextData());
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="App.Views.HomePage" Title="All"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
            x:DataType="vm:PostsViewModel"
            xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
            >
    <!--<ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding DisappearingCommand}" EventName="Disappearing" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>-->

    <CollectionView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Posts}"
        BackgroundColor="#1C1D20"
        RemainingItemsThreshold="5"
        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached">
        <!--<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>-->
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border 
                        Stroke="#1C1D20" 
                        StrokeThickness="0" 
                        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15"  
                        Grid.RowSpan="5"
                        Margin="10"
                        Padding="10"
                        HeightRequest="75"
                        WidthRequest="75"
                        >
                        <Image 
                            Grid.RowSpan="5"
                            Source="{Binding Link.Image.ImageUrl, StringFormat='https://discuit.net{0}'}"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HeightRequest="80"
                            WidthRequest="80" />
                    </Border>
                    <Label 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                        MaxLines="2"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        Padding="0,10,5,0"
                        />
                    <Label 
                        x:Name="communityAndUserLabel"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        FontAttributes="None"
                        VerticalOptions="End">
                        <Label.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} • {1}">
                                <Binding Path="CommunityName" />
                                <Binding Path="Username" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Label.Text>
                        <Label.TextColor>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommunityTextColorConverter}">
                                <Binding 
                                Path="CommunityName" Source="x:Reference communityAndUserLabel" />
                                <Binding 
                                Path="Username" Source="x:Reference communityAndUserLabel" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Label.TextColor>
                    </Label>
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        TextColor="Grey"
                        FontAttributes="None">
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:M/d/y - ddd h:mmt} • {1}">
                            <Binding Path="CreatedAt" />
                            <Binding Path="Link.Hostname" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="4"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        TextColor="Grey"
                        FontAttributes="None"
                        VerticalOptions="End" 
                        Padding="0,0,0,10">
                        <Label.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Upvotes • {1} Downvotes • {2} Comments">
                                <Binding Path="Upvotes" />
                                <Binding Path="Downvotes" />
                                <Binding Path="NoComments" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Label.Text>
                    </Label>
                    <BoxView
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        HeightRequest="3" 
                        Color="Black" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

What I'm seeing now is that everything populates as expected until I hit this in the ViewModel:

```
if (content.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content.Content, options);
            Console.WriteLine("Status OK");
        }
```

Once it runs the Data = line, the values change so that everything looks like its value is the name of itself (i.e. endPoint changes from "/posts" to "endPoint".  Then, when the code enters the FetchNextData function from the Codebehind via

```
await Task.Run(() => vm.FetchNextData());
```

all values become null, with the exception of Data.Next - which retains its value.

Comment: CollectionView has built in support for incremental loading.  However you fetch the additional data, you would just append it to the existing `ItemsSource`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally

Comment: Thanks as always @Jason.  I've read this documentation now (I didn't know exactly what I was trying to do was called - "incremental loading" - so didn't see it before, thank you for the link); however I'm getting an error that I don't understand.  Bing chat and search are not getting me anywhere with the error either.  I'm going to add it to my Question so it'll be easier to read and so I can add details, if you don't mind taking a look when you get a chance.

Comment: event handlers go in the code behind, not the VM

Comment: I've done what I think I needed to do to fix that, but now I'm getting a page with no posts loading instead of the 10 that were there before I started - so I need to do some more digging.  Adding what I've done to the question.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do in your last edit - if you want to access your VM from the code behind, you can easily do that without this amount of extra work

Comment: Like without adding the interface?  I got that advice from Bing chat when I asked it how to access the VM from the codebehind .  I'd definitely like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: yes, the page should already have a reference to it's VM

Comment: Ok cool.  I backed all of that back off and cleaned up the mess I made.  I think I'm really close now, but I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when hitting **var content = await vm.client.GetAsync(request);** inside of the OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached()

Comment: you really need to figure out how to use the debugger.  Something is null - figure out what it is.  Where do you initialize `client`?

Comment: 100%.  client is initialized (currently) in the VM inside of LoadPosts().  I was worried about how I reuse it again because of what is mentioned about sockets in the answer below, but yeah it sounds like something isn't getting passed through?  I'll take a break and go read about the VS debugger :)

Comment: Looks like the only thing that *isn't* null is vm.Data.Next;

Comment: If you post your code somewhere I’ll take a look.  Doing this via a comment thread is impossible

Comment: I've removed everything referring to an interface since that was unneeded, and updated the code so that it is current and makes sense in the current comment context.  I appreciate it.

Comment: What is the current state of the code?  Is it working?

Comment: Everything is working except the OnCollecctionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached() in the codebehind.  If I don't reference that in the View then everything works (except that it will only pull in 10 items since there's no incremental loading without it).

vm.Client and vm.EndPoint are null inside OnCollectionRemainingItemsThresholdReached, but Client and EndPoint themselves have the expected values.

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception?  What is the **specific** problem?  Why isn't all that code in the VM?  ie, you should have a VM method `FetchNextData()` or something that encapsulates all of that code

Comment: Oh, I see.  So then I would call FetchNextData() from the OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached()?

Comment: yes, the code behind calls the VM method to do the actual work

Comment: I got this done (please see edits to Question when you can), but it's still the same problem with everything going null .

Comment: I'm not going to continue to debug this via a comment thread.  As I suggested before, share the solution and I'll look at it, or learn to use the debugger.  A null ref is a very basic C# issue you need to learn to deal with

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?  Like you don't want me commenting on here again until I've figured it out on my own? I added the changes you recommended to the Answer before the last comment. and I've been learning to use the debugger already - that's how I found where I'm losing the value - I'm just not sure where to go from there or why that is happening.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line that is failing, and check every object on that line to determine which one is null.  Then figure out why.  If you post your entire solution somewhere I can get it I will take a quick look for you.

Comment: Oh, I get it :) - will this work?: https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc

That sounds like what I've done, except for the figure out why part.  I think I maybe need to store the data before it goes null and retrieve it in the function?  Everything except Data.Next goes null after calling the function in the VM from the codebehind with await Task.Run(() => vm.FetchNextData());  

I really appreciate you looking at this for me when you get a chance!

Comment: `var Client = new RestClient...` this creates a **new local instance** of `Client` instead of using the class instance you've already declared.  So that in the other method when you use `Client` it is null.  Get rid of the `var` keyword to use the class instance.  You are doing the same thing with `endPoint` (and possibly others)

Comment: hmm... got that done, but they are still nulling out it seems after running through 'Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content. Content, options);' - I thought maybe I'd try making them stronger by assigning a value in the class to see if that would help (among a few other failed ideas), but that causes an infinite loop of reloading EVERYTHING and resetting the view back to the top on each loop.  

Comment: Nulling directly after entering FetchNextData() probably is a better way to put it (or upon exiting LoadPosts() depending on how you look at it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
// add a Posts collection, update your XAML to use this as the ItemsSource
public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

// initialize these variables, they do not change
public string baseUrl { get; set; } = "https://discuit.net/api";
public string endPoint { get; set; } = "/posts";
public RestClient Client { get; set; }

// add a constructor to initialize objects
public PostsViewModel()
{
    var clientoptions = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl)
    {
        //Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("discapp", "testing123")
    };

    Client = new RestClient(
                            clientoptions,
                            configureSerialization: s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson()
        );

    Posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>();
}

// only need one method to request data
// update the incremental event handler to call this
public async Task LoadPosts()
{
    string url = endPoint;

    // add the parameter for Next page of data
    if (Data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data.Next))
    {
        url += "?next=" + Data.Next;
    }

    var request = new RestRequest(url);
    var content = await Client.GetAsync(request);

    //set json options
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    };

    if (content.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
    {
        Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(content.Content, options);

        // we want to add to the existing Posts collection
        foreach (var p in Data.Posts)
        {
            Posts.Add(p);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Status OK");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
    }
}
```

update:

to prevent the load from running every time the event fires

```
bool flag = false;

public async Task LoadPosts()
{
   if (flag) return;

   flag = true;

   // do stuff

   flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Something interesting going on in the foreach I think, but not sure what.  It starts repeating the same 10 posts over and over in somewhat random increments (counted 9, then 15, then 24 repeats).  Won't be near a computer for a couple of days, but will be interesting to look into next week!

Comment: Hey @Jason - I've been trying to figure out what is going on with this, and I've narrowed it down to that every time I scroll down and hit the threshold, it fires off multiple times, and within that sometimes LoadPosts is launched multiple times between each threshold limit being reached.  Any advice as to what might be causing this?

Comment: use a simple `bool` flag to prevent it from running multiple times

Comment: Guessing what I've done [here](https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc/blob/master/Views/HomePage.xaml.cs) is not what you meant.  I also tried something out with binding on the [VM](https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc/blob/master/ViewModels/PostsViewModel.cs), but no go there either.

Comment: your logic is bad.  See my edit

Comment: Ah okay, I see how that should work.  Thank you again.  Seems to limit LoadPosts() to only running once after the threshold is reached though, then no more posts will ever load again.

Comment: no, you reset it to false after it completes its work

Comment: Same thing, but in OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached() seems to work!

Just saw your response, I'm guessing where I stuck the reset to false must be unreachable, I'll take a look.  Thank you again for all the help!!

Comment: Yep, I had it just outside of the if/else 

Answer (score 1):

> At the very end of the json returned from the API I'm using, there is
> a "next" element. I've worked out that I need to append this to the
> api url to get the next set of 10 results, and so on.

Usually when paging, you have total count of records, and the records of the current page. When using collection view incremental loading, you do not really
care about that, you just repeat the request with skipping records.
(Skip 220, get 10)

> Do I make a new RestClient/httpclient to get the next set of results?

No, you use the same HttpClient. Otherwise, you can burn your sockets out, pretty quick. At some point you will notice, that MAUI is running on many OS, and just because something is Disposable, it does not mean that resources are returned to the OS. And once you run out of sockets... good luck handling those exceptions.
(I am yet to see unconditionally working HttpClientFactory on MAUI btw, handling all by myself for now)

> Is there any documentation that shows how this is supposed to be done?

The one thing that you should care about is when you add your 100 items, you do not fire 100 events. This is used by RangeObservableCollection. (An Observable Collection that can add items to it, without firing notifications if needed)

So, quick answer, you need to search:

1. RemainingItemsThresholdReached
2. RangeObservableCollection

Btw, if you test it on Win you might see some issues, I remember people complaining about it. Android/IOS should work.

Comment: Thank you.  This has a lot of good info that I was able to use, but I'm still having an issue (added to the bottom of my question) so I'm not sure if I should select this as the answer yet or not?